# Const methods to access private data members in C++

Tags: c++, methods, constants, private

My project is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/foq27lafefoes7d/lab3.zip?dl=0
I have lots of other errors but I made sure that I wasn't trying to redefine a string literal or anything before asking this.

```
    void Player::Display() const
{
    cout << "\nPlayer Name:  " << GetName() << 
        "\nGrade:        " << GetGrade() << "\nG.P.A.        " << GetGPA() << endl;
}
```

The problem occurs in here, I get access violations, is there a way to this while keeping Display const or is this code valid and my problem is somewhere else and not being caught in the debugger?

```
    //Getters FOUND OUT THESE NEED TO BE CONSTANT RETURN TYPES AS WELL
const char* Player::GetName() const {return m_name;}
const int Player::GetGrade() const {return m_grade;}
const double Player::GetGPA() const {return m_gpa;}
```

more relevant code,
So I learned that to read a private data member with a const method like this, you have to make two const "promises" not to change the privates

```
 class Player
{
public:
    char* GetName() const;
    int GetGrade() const;
    double GetGPA() const;


private:
    char* m_name;
    int m_grade;
    double m_gpa;

};
```

Comment: Where are the errors?

Comment: I think `GetName()` should return a `const char*`.

Comment: Your code looks fine (except that I would make `Player::GetName()` return `const char*`), so the problem is elsewhere - most likely something is not initialized in `Player`.

Comment: You mean you get access violations at runtime? Then have a look at the stack trace. Also, I'd rather use `std::string` for the player name. And the return value of `GetName()` should be declared `const char*`, if you stick with `char*` for `m_name`.

Comment: Hope you have declared & defined Display() function, moreover what error are you facing, sharing them might help

Comment: Put an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. I bet on `m_name` not being initialised properly, but it's impossible to tell without seeing a *minimal* reproducing example. I am not downloading ZIP files for that, it should really be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get any compilation  errors, the probable cause is returning a `char*` instead of `const char*` from `GetName()`. If the name is initialized with readonly memory (ie. using double quotes like `"Tom"`) and you try to write characters to the pointer returned by `GetName()`, you will get an access violation.

Comment: That was it! GetName() needed to return a const char*             const int Player::GetGrade() const {return m_grade;} fixed all problems